# How to get disk type (SSD, HDD, Optical) on macOS using DiskArbitration or other framework

Tags: swift, macos, diskarbitration

I am trying to figure out how I can get some additional disk properties on macOS using Swift. I am especially interested in the type of disk (like SSD, HDD, Optical).

I am getting a list of mounted volumes using the following code:

```
FileManager.default.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil)
```

I am then iterating over all volumes and get additional properties like total disk space using property keys:

```
for volumeUrl in mountedVolumeURLs {
  if let values = try? volumeUrl.resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeTotalCapacityKey, .volumeNameKey, .volumeIsInternalKey] {
     // Do something
  }
}
```

I could not find a resource key to get the type. I then saw that there is an additional framework called `DiskArbitration`.

I used to following code to get the BSD Name in hope to find the type using IOReg, but this did not help me either (I am only using this code to get the bad name, I think the DiskArbitration is for unmounting / mounting volumes only).

```
if let session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault)
{
  let mountedVolumeURLs = FileManager.default.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil)!

  for volumeURL in mountedVolumeURLs
  {
    if let disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(kCFAllocatorDefault, session, volumeURL as CFURL)
    {
      if let bsdname = DADiskGetBSDName(disk)
      {
        let bsdString = String(cString : bsdname)
        print(volumeURL.path, bsdString)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get this information with a (public) framework on macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close, there is an API `DADiskCopyDescription` in `DiskArbitration` which returns a dictionary with a lot of information

```
if let session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault)
{
    let mountedVolumeURLs = FileManager.default.mountedVolumeURLs(includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil)!
    for volumeURL in mountedVolumeURLs
    {
        if let disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(kCFAllocatorDefault, session, volumeURL as CFURL)
        {
            if let diskInfo = DADiskCopyDescription(disk) as? [String:Any]
            {
                print(volumeURL.path, diskInfo)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But as far as I know it doesn't show the information whether the disk is SSD or HD, this could be determined with the IORegistry in `IOKit`.

Comment: Thank you, this should be a good starting point.

Comment: How can we get all volumes urls e.g "mountedVolumeURLs" in C++.

Comment: Is there some means to get a list of drives that are not mounted but are in /dev? I am working on some code that will unencrypt bitlocker drives on a Mac but the drive is not mounted and the name will change everytime it is connected.  Everything I've found so far all use mounted drives

Comment: @linuxgnuru You can get the information of the connected but unmounted disks with `diskutil` (shell command)

Comment: I tried this however I get "Could not start up a DiskManagment sesion" error

Comment: No, this is not part of the framework, you have to ask the shell via [`Process`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process)